# Bundle size differs with import convention for Material UI

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I'm using material-ui@next (v1.0.0-beta.38)

In our existing project developers has followed the different convention for importing components from Material UI. As follows:

```
// Case #1
import Button from "material-ui/Button";     // 121.8K (gzipped: 33.9K)

// Case #2
import Button from "material-ui/es/Button";  // 101.8K (gzipped: 29.4K)
```

After production bundle (using webpack), the size of material ui is as below:

[image]

Now I updated the code and only keep **Case #1** convention and got below result:

[image]

So, we can understand that es version code increase the vendor bundle size. But If we can see above code snippet that **Case #2** import size *(~29K)* is less compared to **Case #1** *(~34K)*, which reducing code bundle size.

**Question #1:** Why es version code added extra?

**Question #2:** Which convention we should follow and why?

Comment: may be related to the very last line here https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#ecmascript